# HTML5 iOS App Swipe Gestures And Getting Data

Tags: ios, html

I am currently building my first HTML5 iOS app.  Here is a screenshot of the HTML5/CSS3 app so far - http://prntscr.com/3km4wd

I want the app to be like the Medium.com app so that the user can swipe across and it will load a new quote, also I need to know how another quote can be loaded up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) in your html/javascript for swipe and many more gestures.